# Inject that SVG at the top of the document by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

I want use svg sprite in my angular project. I see [css-tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) and in this article mention to the method with `include_once` to inject SVG sprites to top of the page.and then use like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon shape-codepen">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-codepen"></use>
</svg>
```

How can i do that in javascript way? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may call below function on body onload to achieve this:

```
function loadSvgTag() {
        var svgTag = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon shape-codepen">use xlink:href="#shape-codepen"></use></svg>';
        document.body.innerHTML = svgTag+document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I want load a SVG file, not just a svg tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an SVG injector like [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject). This way you can keep your SVG in an external file, which will be injected into the HTML DOM during runtime. This works on all browsers that support SVG.

A full example may look like this (where image.svg contains your SVG):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="svg-inject.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="image.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```